# How do I plot gam model response predictions on a (hemi)spherical heatmap in R?

Tags: 3d, mgcv

I have built a model with a spherical smooth term containing separate smooths for each level of a factor (formulated as s(lat,lon, bs = "sos", by = factor)) using gam() in the mgcv package in R. Now I would like to plot the predicted response of my model as a contour plot/heatmap on a sphere. My lat variable (in degrees) falls in the interval [0,90] and lon [0,360], so technically I'm aiming to plot a hemisphere and not a sphere.

I could do this using the plot.gam() function, however, this plots the model on the scale of the predictors, according to the function documentation. As my model consists of multiple smooths, it isn't feasible for me to force plotting on the response scale using the shift and trans arguments in plot.gam().

After some searching, it seems there is no way to conveniently plot my model on the response scale, so I have opted to simulate some data and generate a response using predict(model, type = "response"). I can get the predictions no problem, but I'm not sure how to manually generate a spherical contour plot? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why isn't it feasible to plot on the response scale? `shift` would add the constant and `trans` would allow the inverse of the link. You would be plotting the partial effect of the SOS smooth on the response scale then, which as this is an additive model is completely fine. While I think doing this via a hypothetical (generating new data to predict at, which forces you to specify data values for the other terms in the model) is the best way, I'm not seeing why you can't plot one smooth on the response scale.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that I have separate smooths for each level of a categorical variable i.e. the "by =" argument is included in the smooth term. The function documentation indicates that shift and trans make sense only with single smooth terms, so doesn't the use of by = makes the use of plot.gam infeasible, since the term generates a seperate smooth for each factor-level?